# Which way do htaccess rules cascade?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to archive an old website behind a /v4 directory on the new website. I was hoping that the below .htaccess was going to redirect any page from the example website to its corresponding page archived under the new domain. However, when I just tested the site it appears that `example.org.au/contact.asp` just went to `newdomain.com/v4/` instead of `newdomain.com/v4/contact.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.org\.au$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ https://newdomain.com/v4/$1.html [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://newdomain.com/v4/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

The second RewriteRule is there for when people just go to the root domain but is it overriding everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this, and also your first rule was set to ignore example.org.au so would never fire. This will process any host served by the site. If that's not what you want let me know:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ https://newdomain.com/v4/$1.html [R=302,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ https://newdomain.com/v4/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks heaps - still getting my head around server side things, not my natural space. What do you mean by "process any host served by the site"? I noticed the old example site wasn't included which makes sense to me but is there any reason I would have put it in there? (I would have got it from somewhere when I was reading about how to do this).

Comment: Glad it's working. If more than one host was being served from the same site, you might want to choose which one a rule applies to using a RewriteCond like you had. I was just checking that wasn't your intention.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, just the one host. Thanks again.

Comment: You probably want to change those 302's to 301's now it's working, making them permanent redirects instead of temporary.